# why one tcp connection cannot send several requests?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

i have a client connect to server via tcp,i only want to create one connection,then use a for loop to send data,but the program does not work,from the server side i can see the client only send data to server once,i don't know why,this is my client code,

```
def recv_req(_sock):
    try:
        h = _sock.recv(4)
        total_len = struct.unpack("!I", h)[0]
        left = total_len - 4
        mystr=""
        while left > 0:
            tmp=_sock.recv(left)
            if not len(tmp):
                break
            mystr += tmp
            left -= len(tmp)
        return mystr
    except:
        print format_exc()
        return
conn = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', 5599))
for i in range(3):
    conn.sendall(buf)
    rbuf=recv_req(conn)
```

the client error is this:it show the first recv is sucess,but the second recv is crash.when i move the create_connection into the loop,it works well,i don't know why this works

> 10
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "white_checker.py", line
>   28, in recv_req
>       total_len = struct.unpack("!I", h)[0] error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "white_checker.py", line 63,
>   in download_samples
>       conn.sendall(buf)   File "/home/work/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Have a look at the variable `h`, which seems to be too short to unpack `I`.

Comment: Use print h to make h has length of 4.